# Why this difference between "dir/" and "dir" with rsync

Tags: linux, directory, rsync

I have been wrestling with something I don't understand with what I thought is a simple `rsync` command line.

```
 rsync -u -v -r -n  "~/usb/.notes/_tech"  "~/.notes/_tech"
```

Where the: `usb` node is a mount point for a (*known*) usb.  The question is that the following two variations give radically different results.

**Example 1**.

```
  $ rsync -u -v -r -n  "~/usb/.notes/_tech"  "~/.notes/_tech" | tee | wc -l
      :

  sent 94,378 bytes  received 6,340 bytes  201,436.00 bytes/sec
  total size is 13,222,770,177  speedup is 131,285.07 (DRY RUN)
```

- **2,024** lines (about ~ 2,020 x files)

**Example 2**.

```
  $ rsync -u -v -r -n  "~/usb/.notes/_tech/"  "~/.notes/_tech/" | tee | wc -l
      :

  sent 88,352 bytes  received 334 bytes  177,372.00 bytes/sec
  total size is 13,222,770,177  speedup is 149,096.48 (DRY RUN)
```

- **23** lines (around 19 x files)

T*herefore* ... I figure example #1 is giving me *All* files on that tree. While, example #2 is more-as I expected (doesn't mean it was '*correct*' though).

***Questions***:

1. Why is there a difference at all?!
2. Which syntax choice provides this simple, recursive, update of a folder sub-tree?
3. What is the underlying reason(s) behind such a *vast difference*?

   - For example; over the weekend, I figured-out that I need to use `ls -lt**c**` when considering `rsync` commands.  (Obvious once you realise that).
   - Also that "*size does matter*" when talking about `rsync`.
   - I can accept a difference in semantics for the "`dir/`" versus the "`dir`" (no slash).  I can't see how with a recurse switch (`-r`) there be much / if any difference.

I don't see a structural issue in the example; so I'm seeking wisdom from the stackoverflow?!!  Insights?

Wisdom sought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to all your questions is in the manual page:

```
A trailing slash on the source changes this behavior to avoid
creating an additional  directory level at the destination.
You can think of a trailing / on a source as meaning "copy the
contents of this directory" as  opposed to  "copy the directory
by name", but in both cases the attributes of the containing
directory are transferred to the containing directory on the
destination.
```

So `rsync -r /foo/ /tmp` will put everything in `/foo` into `/tmp` whereas `rsync -r /foo /tmp` will put everything in `/foo` into `/tmp/foo`.

Comment: Thanks, I see now ... _RTFM_, OK that's good.